# How to do an SQL style search query in google cloud datastore?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, sql-like

Google Cloud **datastore** does not allow to make SQL style search queries like

```sql
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name LIKE "Rob*"
```

that would return `Rob, Robert, Roberto, Roberta, Roby` and so on.

GCP **datastore** only allows to filter on fields using operators: `>, >=, <, <=` with rules like:

- any upper case letter is smaller than any lower case letter
- `a < b < c < ... < z`

With these rules, the query

```golang
query := datastore.NewQuery("Person").Filter("Name >= ", "Rob").Order("Name")
```

would not only return all Person whose name starts with `Rob`, but also all Person whose name is greater than `Rob` (Ruben, Sarah, Zoe) and all Person whose names starts with a lower case letter.

The present post is a hack that I found in Go to emulate a SQL style search query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution addresses the issue programmatically. It is coded in `go` but i believe it could be easily adapted to any language.

I'll first produce the whole snippet and then I shall break it down.

```golang
func (store *PersonStore) Search(name string) ([]Person, error) {
    context := context.Background()
    persons := make([]*Person, 0)
    query := datastore.NewQuery("Person").Filter("Name >= ", strings.ToLower(name)).Order("Name")

    keys, err := store.client.GetAll(context, query, &persons)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to search for persons w/ names containing %s - %v", name, err)
    }

    filteredPersons := make([]*Perons, 0)
    for i, p := range persons {
        p.ID = keys[i].ID
        if !strings.Contains(p.Name, strings.ToLower(name)) {
            break
        } else {
            filteredPersons = append(filteredPersons, p)
        }
    }
}
```

#### 1 - Lower case assumption

In order for this code to work we first need to make a very strong assumption that **all names are in lower case**. If, for some reason, you cannot make this assumption, you can still partially use this code, but it will be less efficient.

#### 2 - Query the datastore

The first part of the code is dedicated to fetching the datastore for Persons whose name is matching the desired pattern.

```golang
    context := context.Background()
    persons := make([]*Person, 0)
    query := datastore.NewQuery("Person").Filter("Name >= ", strings.ToLower(name)).Order("Name")

    keys, err := store.client.GetAll(context, query, &persons)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to search for persons w/ names containing %s - %v", name, err)
    }
```

We make sure we use `strings.ToLower(name)` to make sure we won't fetch **ALL** `Person`s. Ideally `name` should be also trimmed, but this is usually done in the front-end, so we ommitted this here.

Once again, this is base on the assumption that all `Name`s are in lower case. If you cannot assume this, you can always use

```
query := datastore.NewQuery("Person").Filter("Name >= ", name).Order("Name")
```

You'll just simply get an initial list with (*possibly a lot*) more `Person`s.

Finally, we order our fetched list with `.Order("Name")` as this is going to be the base point of the second part of the code.

#### 3 - Filter on Names

Up to here it was a simple `GetAll` piece of code. We still need to insert the keys into the `Person` structures. We need to find a way to optimize that. For this we can rest on the fact that `persons` and `keys` list are in exact length and order. So the upcoming `for` loop starts exactly like a regular insert Key into structure bit.

```golang
    for i, p := range persons {
        p.ID = keys[i].ID
```

The next bit is where the optimization is: since we know that the `Person`s are ordered by `Name` we are certain that, as soon as `strings.Contains(p.Name, strings.ToLower(name))` is not true we have selected all `Person`s whose `Name` matches our criteria, that is, as soon as `p.Name` doesn't start with `Rob` anymore but with `Roc` or `Rod` or anything lexicographically greater than this.

```golang
        if !strings.Contains(p.Name, strings.ToLower(name)) {
            break
```

We can then escape our loop using a `break` instruction, hopefuly having only parsed the first few elements of `persons` list that matche our criteria. These fall into the `else` statement:

```golang
        } else {
            filteredPersons = append(filteredPersons, p)
        }
```

#### 4 - Filter on Names without the lower case assumption

As I said earlier, if you cannot assume all names are in lower case, you can still use this code, but it will not be optimized, because you will mandatorily have to scan the full `persons` list returned by the query.

The code should look liske this

```golang
    filteredPersons := make([]*Perons, 0)
    for i, p := range persons {
        p.ID = keys[i].ID
        if strings.Contains(p.Name, strings.ToLower(name)) {
            filteredPersons = append(filteredPersons, p)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for prefix matches you can use multiple inequality filters on the same property.  I.e. from https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries "If a query has multiple inequality filters on a given property, an entity will match the query only if at least one of its individual values for the property satisfies all of the filters."

The example on that page is `SELECT * FROM Task WHERE tag > 'learn' AND tag < 'math'`.  Or for your case `query := datastore.NewQuery("Person").Filter("Name >= ", "Rob").Filter("Name <= Rob~").Order("Name")`

Comment: Damn! Nice and simple! I'm going to try that ASAP. +1 vote

Comment: BTW, I love your name, Lizard King :)